# @Min and @Max validation is not working of hibernate validator package in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

@Min and @Max validator is not working as the value is getting assigned to a static variable from the properties file. But it taking all the value and not validating.

**OTPLengthAndExpiryDetail.java**

```
package com.custom.store.sms.twillo.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Component
@Validated
public class OTPLengthAndExpiryDetail {
    
    @Min(value = 4 , message = "Value should be greater then then equal to 4")
    @Max(value = 6 , message = "Value should be less then then equal to 6")
    @NotNull(message = "It can not be null. Please provide no. in b/w 4 to 6")
    @Value("${otp.length}")
    private static Integer length;
    
    @Min(value = 20 , message = "Value should be greater then equal to 20")
    @Max(value = 180 , message = "Value should be less then equal to 180")
    @NotNull(message = "It can not be null. Please provide no. in b/w 20 to 300")
    @Value("${otp.expiryTime}")
    private static Integer expiryTime;

    public static Integer getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(Integer length) {
        OTPLengthAndExpiryDetail.length = length;
    }

    public static Integer getExpiryTime() {
        return expiryTime;
    }

    public void setExpiryTime(Integer expiryTime) {
        OTPLengthAndExpiryDetail.expiryTime = expiryTime;
    }
    
}
```

**application.properties**

```
#1. ################       DB DETAILS        ###############################
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com/q5UV1n69DW?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=q5
spring.datasource.password=ur
############################################################################



#2. ##############     LOGGING DETAILS FOR APPLICATION     #################
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
#logging.level.org.hibernate=debug
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
############################################################################



#3.###############       TWILLO DETAILS FOR OTP      #######################
#both below twillo details can't be null                        
twilio.accountSID=AC53bec33dc8bae99f8                                     
twilio.authId=7c31ef0e28e75473
twilio.phoneNumber=16468634753                    
############################################################################



#4.###############     OTP CONFIGURATION DETAILS     #######################
#otp.length can not be null. Please provide no. in b/w 4 to 6
otp.length=4
#otp.expirytime can not be null. Please provide no. in b/w 20 to 300
otp.expiryTime=2000
otp.message=your otp is 
############################################################################
```

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.custom.store'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation group: "com.twilio.sdk", name: "twilio", version : "7.47.2"
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    //implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.1.5.Final"
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**OTPProperties.java** *  it is the class where I am instantiating the custom Configuration*

```
package com.custom.store.sms.twillo.conf;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import com.custom.store.sms.twillo.model.OTPLengthAndExpiryDetail;
import com.custom.store.sms.twillo.model.TwilioAccountAndAuthDetail;


@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class OTPProperties {
    
    //@Autowired
    TwilioAccountAndAuthDetail twilio;
    
    //@Autowired
    OTPLengthAndExpiryDetail otp;

    public TwilioAccountAndAuthDetail getTwilio() {
        return twilio;
    }

    public void setTwilio(TwilioAccountAndAuthDetail twilio) {
        this.twilio = twilio;
    }

    public OTPLengthAndExpiryDetail getOtp() {
        return otp;
    }

    public void setOtp(OTPLengthAndExpiryDetail otp) {
        this.otp = otp;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to chapter 3 section 1 of [JSR-303](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303):

> Static fields and static methods are excluded from validation.

Therefore, `length` and `expiryTime` should not be designated as `static` fields if you wish to apply validation to them.

Comment: Is there any way to validate the static variable?

Comment: both the variables are constant and it's loaded one time when the class gets initialized so. It should be static.  Is there any way to validate the static fields?

Comment: @Raghawendrasingh Why not make them final instance fields, then?

Comment: I am using those two variables inside the static block. And inside a static block, only static variables can be used. That's why by making it only final it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, @PhilipWrage it worked by making final instance fields.